# printing plots with dashed/dotted to TIFF

Tags: matlab

I am trying to print a MATLAB line plot to a TIFF file.  However, when I do this, the dashed and dotted lines appear as solids.  Is there away to fix this?

Comment: It seems to work when I set the image quality really low ~80dpi, but I would still like to be able to use dotted lines at a higher quality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the `painters` renderer, which usually solves this. Also, in general, you might like the [`export_fig()`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629) function from FileExchange.